# How can I edit the URL without changing pages?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I want to edit the URL of the page without changing to another. Something like this:

```
For Example: Original URL: localhost:3000/sagsdfgs
             New URL: localhost:3000/fgdgs
```

Same Host, different URL, same page. I think in react-router-dom there is a function, but I don't remember what the function is called and I looked for it but I didn't find it

Comment: it's tough to answer without any clarifications on the question, and example of what you have already done.

Comment: The question is unclear.  The react [router documentation](https://v5.reactrouter.com/) provides various ways to create an alias or redirect, but the question doesn't provide enough information to suggest a solution.

Comment: Do you just want to render the same component on both paths? Can you clarify the issue and provide a [mcve] for what you are trying to accomplilsh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out !

```
let url = window.location.toString();
window.location = url.replace(/function=login/, '/function=userloggedIn/');
```